# Delete all sublists of nested list of list

Tags: python

I want to delete all the duplicate sublists and only leave the list that contain the most.

#### Given

I have this example

```
[
    [[1981 ,1983, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989]],
    [[1982 ,1984, 1985]],
    [[1983 , 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988 ,1989]]
    [[1984 , 1985]],
    [[1985 , 1986 , 1987 , 1988 ,1989]]
    
]
```

#### Expected

```
[
    [[1981, 1983, 1985, 1986 ,1987, 1988, 1989]],
    [[1982, 1984, 1985]],
    [[1984 ,1985]],
]
```

#### Problem

I have list of list of list which make it hard for me

Comment: There is one ] missing in input list can you please correct it?

Comment: The expected output is still missing a bracket. Also, shouldn't the input be like `[[[1]],[[2]],[[4]],[[3,4,5]],[[5]], [[3,4]]]`?

Comment: yes I just re edited it

Comment: You don't need the else block, use `if not any(....)`

Comment: What if you have `[[2,3],[3,4]]` do you keep both?

Comment: yes we keep it in that way! we delete only if the whole sublist exist in another list

Comment: Can the lists have missing numbers? for instance `[1,5]`? why do you use this slice `[idx + 2:]`? I don't understand this part, anyway I don't think that you can have anything better of O(N^2) if you can have missing numbers

Comment: No no only the list that  already exist , I don't want to create new lists only delete the duplicated ones

Comment: No, sorry I wasn't clear, is this a valid input `[[1,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]`?

Comment: No no sorry , that can not be the case since it is ordered so I can have input ````[[[1,2,3,4,5]], [[2,3,4,5]], [[3,4,5,6]]] ````  and as output  ````[[[1,2,3,4,5]],  [[3,4,5,6]]] ````

Comment: oh, ok then things are really different

Comment: For the expected output, why does `[2]` remain but `[4]` and `[5]` don't?

Comment: you are right it should not

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I didn't come up with a great solution imo, I wonder if you can do better than this somehow, you definitely have to check for each list if it's a sublist which is at least O(n^2).

```
def is_sublist(sub_list: list, lst: list):
   return all(n in lst for n in sub_list):


#mini optimization I reverse sort the array by length so I can stop searching when the length of the list is lower than the sublist
array = sorted(array, key = lambda subl: len(subl), reverse = True)

for i, sub_list in enumerate(array):
   for j, lst in enumerate(array):
      if len(lst) < len(sub_list):
         break 
      if i!=j and is_sublist(sublist, lst): 
         array.remove(sub_list) 
         break
```

Since you clarified that things are a little different than what I thought initially, the problem is way simpler, each list is just a range(n, m) and you can first order the array and then check left and right for each element in linear time

```
def is_subrange(subrange, larger_range):
   x1, x2 = subrange[0], subrange[-1]
   y1, y2 = larger_range[0], larger_range[-1]
   return x1 >= y1 and x2 <= y2

array = sorted(array)
i = 0 
while i<len(array): 
   if i+1 < len(array) and is_subrange(array[i], array[i+1]): # checks succesive element
      del array[i]
   elif i-1 >= 0  and is_subrange(array[i], array[i-1]): # checks previous element
      del array[i]
   else:
      i+=1
```

Comment: The thing is that as an argument I have to give the sublist but I don't know them

Comment: @askingquestions have a look now, I added a solution based on what you added about the problem

Comment: your algorithm actually work really fast but don't know why it just skip some indexes, so we actually have some missing data that are in the original list  ````[1980]
[1981 1983 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989]
[1982 1984 1985]
[1990] ````  instead I get ````[1980]
[1981 1983 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989]
[1990]
[1991] ```` original list looks like this ````[1981 1983 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989]
[1982 1984 1985]
[1983 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989]
[1984 1985]
[1985 1986 1987 1988 1989]````

Comment: Because only ranges are allowed for the second algorithm to work, you stated that [[1,5],[1,2,3,4,5]] was not a valid input in the comments.

Comment: Ah sorry then I misunderstood, the algorithm is fast but I need the other values as well, can u take a look at my algorithm or is there any way to actually update ur algorithm

Comment: no, you need to explain what are the valid inputs and what is the expected output properly.

Comment: I tried to edit the problem again

Comment: Can you explain what are the valid inputs with words? why it now is list of list of numbers and before it was a list of numbers. what kind of numbers are allowed in the lists? can you explain the expected output with words?

Comment: Okay so the idea is that my input is list of nested list but if a whole list is duplicated inside another list it chould be removed, the order of the elements doesn't matter if they exist in a bigger list meaning they are already similar so I need to get rid of the smaller sublist